# Convergence of CDF

Tags: probability-distributions

I have a cumulative probability distribution function F(x).

I need to prove that

$\sum_{n=2}^\infty n(F(x)^{n-1} - F(x)^n)$ does not converge for all $x \in \mathbb{R^+} - \{x:F(x)\ne 0\}$

Comment: It is visibly not pointwise convergence (for an $F$ that is $0$ in $0$, it suffices to take $x=0$ to get a _convergent_ series). Thus convergence should be as a series of functions...

Comment: You can factor $(1-F(x))$ in your series... It will look simpler.  But after that ...

Comment: My apologies, ....only for $x$ such that $F(x) \ne  0$

Comment: That's wrong. $F(x)\in[0,1]$, and $\displaystyle\sum_{n=2}^\infty n(y^{n-1} - y^n)$ is convergent for all $y\in[0,1]$.

Comment: @ProfessorVector could you explain why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's wrong. For $F(x)<1$:$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty n(F(x)^{n-1} - F(x)^n)=(1-F(x))\sum_{n=2}^\infty nF(x)^{n-1}\\=(1-F(x))\dfrac{2F(x)-F^2(x)}{(1-F(x))^2}\\=F(x)\dfrac{2-F(x)}{1-F(x)}$$and for $F(x)=1$:$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty n(F(x)^{n-1} - F(x)^n)=0$$which is convergent at both cases.

Comment: This is wrong, too. $$\sum_{n=2}^\infty nF(x)^{n-1}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty nF(x)^{n-1}-1=\frac1{(1-F(x))^2}-1.$$

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I corrected it....

Comment: I don't agree at all with you when you say: $F(x)<1$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}$ ? If, for instance, $F$ is the "ramp function" associated to a Uniform on [0,1], you have $F(x)=1$ for all $x \in (1,\infty)$ ...

Comment: Now I agree to your corrected answer ...